# THE line of all linear combination?

Tags: linear-algebra

First of all this is not home work question, but a clarification!

This question came up when i am going through Gilbert Strang's Linear algebra question in his book.

Consider two vectors $v$ and $w$, the addition  gives us $v+w$, but the question is asking to draws all linear combination of $cv + dw$ where $c+d=1$, but that can be many lines and The answer to the question also says it is a line,

Can someone please clarify this situation

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restriction $c+d = 1$ means that you have many choices for what $c$ and $d$ may be. For each such choice, you get a vector $cv+dw$. Thus as you try all possible choices for $c$ and $d$, you get a large collection of vectors.

In this context, it may be a good idea to think of vectors not as arrows, but only as points (the end point of a vector starting at the origin), because anything else would get messy quickly. If you take the collection of vectors mentioned earlier, and draw each of them (as points), then the result will be the straight line that goes through the points $v$ and $w$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're asking ("many lines"?) for but perhaps this helps clarifying.

If $c+d=1$, then also $d=1-c$; now substituting and rearranging a bit:
$$\begin{align}cv+dw & = cv+(1-c)w \\ & = \color{blue}{w+c(v-w)}\end{align}$$
You may recognize this as a *parametric form* of the line through $v$ and $w$.

If you're supposed to draw a few of these linear combinations, the idea is probably that after drawing a few, you should begin to notice that they all lie on the line through $v$ and $w$. The algebra above confirms that.

Comment: Thanks. This was really helpful too